# Session in working fine in localhost but not at server

Tags: php, session

Session in working fine in localhost but not at server. I am getting the error"This page isn’t working domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: I feel your pain, but how do you expect anybody here to help you when you give us absolutely no information to be able to help you. **500** errors are complete catastrophies, what makes yo think this is related to the session?

Comment: Please enable PHP error reporting and update your question, so that others can help you.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think your config file have some error

host name
username and password check